# A diferença entre pasto e campo?

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro, uso-de-palavras, diferenças

Qual é a diferença entre *pasto* e *campo*. Por exemplo:

> Cavalo num pasto.
>
> O cavalo está correndo no campo.
>
> A cabra está no pasto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Pasto***, também *pastagem*, é um tipo de campo onde há boa erva para o gado (vacas, cavalos, ovelhas), e o gado é levado para lá para **pastar**, isto é, para se alimentar da erva. Também se chama *pasto* a essa erva.

***Campo*** pode ser pasto, mas também pode ser terra com árvores de fruto, ou trigo, ou batatas, ou outra cultura agrícola qualquer, ou ainda terra não cultivada, com vegetação rasteira e árvores isoladas. Se for uma grande extensão de arvoredo cerrado, chama-se *floresta* ou *mata*. No fundo, *campo* é toda a terra que não é zona urbanizada, nem grande floresta, nem praia.

Podemos falar de ***um campo***, que é um terreno com limites visíveis (cercas, estradas), ou campo em geral, que é o conjunto de todos os campos. Por exemplo:

> Vi **um campo** de papoilas cercado por campos de trigo.
>
> Este ano vou passar metade das férias na praia e a outra metade no **campo** (“campo em geral”).

[Pasto (Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/pasto) tem ainda outros significados relacionados com ’comer’, mas que não têm nada que ver com *campo*. E [campo](http://www.aulete.com.br/campo) (Aulete) tem também outros significados que não tem que ver com terra.

Comment: Muito claro e preciso; a qualidade a que nos habituaste... <3